# Wickes UK stores' postcodes

Tags: data-request, geospatial, postal-code, uk, companies

I'm looking for a spreadsheet of postcodes for Wickes DIY stores in the UK. This is so that I can calculate the distance between customers' postcodes and the stores.

Wickes has a store finder page (http://www.wickes.co.uk/store-finder), with details for over 200 stores. I don't want to mine that data by hand. Has anyone done this before, or have any tools to extract the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be exact, there are 231 stores listed in the dropdown. I was able to extract (fairly simple) the list of stores and corresponding store IDs. I've included the list in CSV format for your convenience. Each store detailed is listed with the following URL sequence:

http://www.wickes.co.uk/store/"STORE_ID"

It should be fairly straight forward to write a program to read in the CSV data and step through each store page and extract out the detailed information (e.g. postcodes). When you accomplish that, please add the info to the CSV data and post in github for the benefit of others.

8276, AINTREE
8475, ALTON
8321, ANDOVER
8360, ASHBY DE LA ZOUCH 
8090, ASHFORD 
8418, ASHTON GATE 
8316, AYLESBURY EXTRA 
8291, BAGULEY 
8277, BANBURY 
8297, BARKING EXTRA 
8247, BARNSLEY 
8256, BARNSTAPLE 
8332, BASINGSTOKE 
8722, BATH KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8729, BATTERSEA KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8727, BECKENHAM K&B 
8264, BEDFORD 
8454, BEVERLEY 
8319, BEXHILL 
8318, BICESTER 
8298, BIRKENHEAD 
8457, BISHOPS STORTFORD 
8281, BLACKHEATH 
8296, BLACKPOOL 
8279, BLETCHLEY 
8467, BOREHAMWOOD 
8355, BOSTON 
8246, BOURNEMOUTH 
8312, BRACKNELL 
8055, BRADFORD 
8438, BRADFORD IDLE 
8381, BRAINTREE 
8409, BRENTWOOD 
8271, BRIDGEND 
8255, BRIDGWATER 
8230, BRIGHTON 
8077, BRISTOL 
8344, BROADSTAIRS 
8364, BULWELL 
8448, BURGESS HILL 
8404, BURTON SOUTH 
8284, BURY 
8347, CAERPHILLY 
8472, CAMBRIDGE 
8208, CANNING TOWN 
8261, CANNOCK 
8422, CARDIFF PENARTH 
8280, CARDIFF WEST 
8253, CARLISLE 
8083, CATFORD 
8372, CHADWELL HEATH 
8466, CHARLTON
8233, CHATHAM 
8232, CHELMSFORD 
8074, CHELTENHAM 
8456, CHESHAM 
8262, CHESTER 
8283, CHESTERFIELD 
8413, CHILWELL 
8349, CHIPPENHAM 
8720, CHISWICK KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8431, CHORLEY 
8715, CHRISTCHURCH KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8724, CLARKSTON KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8236, CLIFTON 
8287, COLCHESTER 
8075, COVENTRY 
8717, CRAWLEY KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8250, CREWE 
8098, CRIBBS 
8072, CRICKLEWOOD 
8215, CROYDON 
8730, CROYDON KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8259, DARLINGTON 
8093, DARTFORD 
8079, DERBY 
8066, DEWSBURY 
8239, DONCASTER 
8240, DORKING 
8252, DUDLEY 
8365, DUMFRIES 
8258, DUNDEE 
8062, DUNSTABLE 
8414, EALING 
8382, EAST GRINSTEAD 
8265, EASTBOURNE
 
8354, EDINBURGH 
8322, EDMONTON EXTRA 
8309, EPSOM 
8310, ERITH 
8336, EXETER 
8228, FAREHAM 
8052, FARNBOROUGH 
8479, FOLKESTONE 
8352, GLASGOW 
8366, GLOSSOP 
8377, GLOUCESTER 
8443, GRANTHAM 
8410, GRAVESEND 
8425, GRIMSBY 
8385, GUILDFORD 
8451, HAILSHAM 
8436, HALESOWEN 
8303, HALIFAX 
8235, HALL GREEN 
8216, HANDSWORTH 
8237, HANGER LANE 
8073, HANWELL 
8260, HANWORTH 
8337, HARLOW EXTRA 
8731, HARROW KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8338, HAVANT EXTRA 
8353, HAVERFORDWEST 
8222, HAYES 
8474, HEDGE END 
8096, HEMEL HEMPSTEAD 
8473, HENDON 
8367, HEREFORD 
8453, HERTFORD 
8313, HIGH WYCOMBE 
8458, HINCKLEY 
8263, HUDDERSFIELD
8053, HULL 
8464, HUNTINGDON 
8295, INVERNESS 
8350, IPSWICH 
8326, KETTERING EXTRA 
8428, KINGS LYNN 
8266, KINGSTON
8251, LANCASTER 
8094, LEICESTER 
8270, LETCHWORTH 
8359, LICHFIELD 
8061, LINCOLN 
8444, LITTLEHAMPTON 
8278, LOUGHBOROUGH 
8317, LOWESTOFT 
8415, MACCLESFIELD 
8314, MAIDSTONE EXTRA 
8449, MALDON 
8368, MANSFIELD
8214, MERTON 
8429, MILTON KEYNES 
8225, MINWORTH 
8728, MUSWELL HILL K&B 
8348, NEWCASTLE EXTRA 
8290, NEWPORT 
8293, NORTHAMPTON 
8218, NORWICH 
8257, NOTTINGHAM 
8071, NOTTINGHAM CENTRAL 
8452, NUNEATON 
8374, OLDHAM 
8726, ORPINGTON KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8234, OXFORD 
8721, PAIGNTON KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8369, PENRITH 
8334, PERRY BARR EXTRA 
8248, PERTH 
8209, PETERBOROUGH 
8370, PLUMSTEAD 
8292, PLYMOUTH 
8267, PONTEFRACT 
8273, PRESTON 
8088, PUDSEY 
8082, RAYLEIGH 
8371, READING 
8220, REDDITCH 
8065, ROTHERHAM 
8078, RUISLIP 
8460, RUSHDEN 
8430, SALISBURY 
8064, SCUNTHORPE 
8411, SEVENOAKS 
8097, SHEFFIELD CENTRAL 
8468, SHEFFIELD CRYSTAL PEAKS 
8412, SHEFFIELD NORTH 
8268, SHREWSBURY 
8320, SITTINGBOURNE 
8340, SLOUGH 
8423, SOUTH GOSFORTH 
8441, SOUTH SHIELDS 
8328, SOUTHAMPTON EXTRA 
8719, SOUTHPORT KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8238, ST ALBANS 
8299, STAFFORD
8416, STEVENAGE 
8417, STIRCHLEY 
8282, STIRLING 
8081, STOCKPORT 
8226, STOCKTON 
8231, STOKE 
8254, SUNDERLAND 
8067, SUTTON (ASHFIELD) 
8482, SUTTON (LONDON) 
8323, SWANSEA EXTRA 
8342, SWINDON EXTRA 
8331, TAMWORTH
8311, TAUNTON EXTRA
8343, TELFORD 
8357, THETFORD 
8091, TOTTENHAM 
8275, TROWBRIDGE 
8407, TRURO 
8723, TUNBRIDGE WELLS KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8455, TUNSTALL
 
8405, TWICKENHAM
8330, UXBRIDGE 
8327, WAKEFIELD 
8229, WALLSEND 
8243, WALTHAM CROSS 
8301, WARRINGTON 
8718, WARWICK KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8227, WATERLOOVILLE 
8245, WATFORD 
8345, WEMBLEY 
8716, WEST HAMPSTEAD KITCHENS & BATHROOMS 
8461, WEST WICKHAM 
8329, WESTON SUPER MARE 
8289, WIGAN 
8059, WIMBLEDON 
8465, WINNERSH 
8459, WINSFORD 
8080, WOKING 
8437, WOLVERHAMPTON 
8406, WORCESTER 
8434, WORKSOP 
8221, WORTHING 
8308, WREXHAM 
8274, YEOVIL 
8471, YORK

I took a look at the HTML code at the store page. It is pretty easy to identify the store name, address and postcode from the javascript code for placing a pin on the Google Map. You get the extra benefit that it has the lat/lon coordinates as well. The snippet looks like:

```
        var storelatitude = '51.157364';<br/>
        var storelongitude = '-0.956997'; <br/>
        var storename = 'ALTON';<br/>
        var storeaddressline1 = 'WICKES UNIT 1, ALTON RETAIL PARK';<br/>
        var storeaddressline2 = 'MILL LANE';<br/>
        var storeaddresstown = 'ALTON';<br/>
        var storeaddresspostalCode = 'GU34 2QS';<br/>
        var storeaddresscountryname = 'United Kingdom';<br/>
```